# Quick way of finding a name of a variable with lowest component value

Tags: r, optimization, goodness-of-fit, fitdistrplus

I have a function fitting a distribution and returning a vector consisting of distribution name, mean, sd, etc.
I'm testing few distributions but I can't rely on gofstat() because it goes mad when there are too many zeros to consider.

Therefore I have to compare manually AIC for several variables, decide which ones are actually of "fitdist" class and return the name of the variable with the lowest AIC. Once I have that, I compute mean, sd, etc and return.

The code currently looks like this:

```
library(fitdistrplus)

fit_distr <- function(data){

fe <- tryCatch(fitdist(data, "exp"), error = function(e) FALSE )
flogis <- tryCatch(fitdist(data, "logis"), error = function(e) FALSE )
fn <- tryCatch(fitdist(data, "norm"), error = function(e) FALSE)
fp <- tryCatch(fitdist(data, "pois"), error = function(e) FALSE)
fg <- tryCatch(fitdist(data, "gamma"), error = function(e) FALSE)

classFitDist <- c(class(fe), class(flogis), class(fn), class(fp),class(fg))

distributions <- classFitDist == "fitdist"


AIC <- data.frame()
if(class(fe)=="fitdist") {AIC[1,ncol(AIC)+1] <- fe$aic}
if(class(flogis)=="fitdist") {AIC[1,ncol(AIC)+1] <- flogis$aic}
if(class(fn)=="fitdist") {AIC[1,ncol(AIC)+1] <- fn$aic}
if(class(fp)=="fitdist") {AIC[1,ncol(AIC)+1] <- fp$aic}
if(class(fg)=="fitdist") {AIC[1,ncol(AIC)+1] <- fg$aic}

names(AIC) <- c("exp", "logis", "norm", "pois", "gamma")[distributions]

fit <- names(AIC[which.min(AIC)])


mean <- switch (fit,
                          exp = 1/fe$estimate[[1]],
                          logis = flogis$estimate[[1]],
                          norm = fn$estimate[[1]],
                          pois = fp$estimate[[1]],
                          gamma = fg$estimate[[1]]/fg$estimate[[2]]
          )

sd <- switch (fit,
                        exp = mean,
                        logis = (flogis$estimate[[2]]*pi)/sqrt(3),
                        norm = fn$estimate[[2]],
                        pois = sqrt(mean),
                        gamma = sqrt(fg$estimate[[1]]/(fg$estimate[[2]]^2))
          )

return(c(fit,mean,sd))
}
```

It works, but on thousands of samples to consider is very slow. I would welcome any suggestions how to optimise it and make it 'cleaner' and faster.

Btw, this is what I had before, however like I mentioned - with samples consisting of too many zeros it was having a fit (pun unintentional!)

```
goodnessoffit <- gofstat(list(fe, flogis, fn, fp, fg)[distributions],  fitnames = c("exp", "logis", "norm", "pois","gamma")[distributions])
fit <- names(which(goodnessoffit$aic == min(goodnessoffit$aic)))
```

> Error in ans[!test & ok] <- rep(no, length.out = length(ans))[!test &  : 
>     replacement has length zero

Comment: A reproducible example is helpful...

Comment: @AdamO you're right, I've expanded the code reproducing a truncated but workable version of the function. You can call it f.i.  fit_distr(rnorm(100)) to test

Comment: Let me see if I understand, for each variable in a dataset, you want to fit 5 distributions and find which one fits best. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly right.

Comment: @ErrHuman: Tried running `fit_distr(rnorm(100));fit_distr(rexp(100,1));` etc. producing error: "<simpleError in optim(par = vstart, fn = fnobj, fix.arg = fix.arg, obs = data,     gr = gradient, ddistnam = ddistname, hessian = TRUE, method = meth,     lower = lower, upper = upper, ...): function cannot be evaluated at initial parameters>"

Comment: I may put together an answer tomorrow. Since these are all special cases of a GLM, you can do a one-step estimator for speed. The distribution fitting is the bottleneck, not the lack of vectorization. Although vectorization will make the code *much* more readable.

Comment: Thank you, AdamO. Looking forward to your answer. I've discovered R only recently and every day is a journey :)

Comment: @bala83 - yes, every time one of the 5 distributions can't be fit, it will throw an error, hence tryCatch() - you get a simpleError, but the function still does what it's meant to do and returns data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with this approach is `fitdist` is inefficient. You need to come up with faster ways of finding the AIC by writing better algorithms. One way of doing that is fitting a `glm`.

```
AIC.fitdist <- function(x, ...) x$aic

x <- rnorm(100, mean=20)

AIC(fitdist(x, 'norm'))
AIC(glm(x ~ 1 , family=gaussian)) ## same

AIC(fitdist(x, 'gamma'))
AIC(glm(x ~ 1 , family=Gamma)) ## same
```

Some profiling shows that `fitdist` has the same computational time as `glm`. That's very bad news for `fitdist` because `glm` is just a bloated wrapper to `glm.fit`. Using `glm.fit` buys you substantial time. Lastly, if you *really* had to prune down time (for millions, not thousands) of models, you can use a one step estimator by

```
> benchmark(
+     fitdist(x, 'gamma'),
+     glm(x ~ 1, family=Gamma),
+     glm.fit(rep(1, length(x)), x, family=Gamma()),
+     glm.fit(rep(1, length(x)), x, family=Gamma(), control = glm.control(maxit=1))
+ )
                                                                               test replications elapsed relative user.self sys.self user.child
1                                                               fitdist(x, "gamma")          100    0.42    7.000      0.42        0         NA
2                                                        glm(x ~ 1, family = Gamma)          100    0.17    2.833      0.17        0         NA
3                                   glm.fit(rep(1, length(x)), x, family = Gamma())          100    0.06    1.000      0.07        0         NA
4 glm.fit(rep(1, length(x)), x, family = Gamma(), control = glm.control(maxit = 1))          100    0.06    1.000      0.06        0         NA
  sys.child
1        NA
2        NA
3        NA
4        NA
```

`aic` is a stored object in `glm.fit` output.

Exponential distribution fitting can be done with `survreg` in the survival package: `survreg(rep(1,100), x, dist='exponential)`.

Lastly, since these are all regular exponential families, you can use the sufficient statistics to just come up with a probability distribution. For instance:

```
normaic <- function(x) {
  4 - 2*sum(dnorm(x, mean(x), sd(x), log=T))
}

> benchmark(normaic(x), glm.fit(rep(1, 100), x)$aic)
                         test replications elapsed relative user.self sys.self user.child sys.child
2 glm.fit(rep(1, 100), x)$aic          100    0.04       NA      0.05        0         NA        NA
1                  normaic(x)          100    0.00       NA      0.00        0         NA        NA
```

Comment: Thank you. I've never used glm or glm.fit before, definitely some food for the brain.